# how to search data in excel worksheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem when searching data from worksheet using a userform button.

`runtime error 424 object required` is generated.

My data from the worksheet starts from row 7

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim totRows As Long
Dim i As Long
'Dim currentregion As Long


totRows = Worksheets("MainSheet").Range("C7").currentregion.Rows.count

If ComboBox5.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "enter case number to search!!"
End If


For i = 7 To totRows
     If Trim(MainSheet.Cells(i, 3)) = Trim(ComboBox5.Value) Then
        ComboBox9.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 2)
        ComboBox1.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        ComboBox2.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        ComboBox5.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        ComboBox8.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        ComboBox9.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 6)
        ComboBox10.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 7)
        ComboBox11.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 8)
        ComboBox12.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 9)
        ComboBox15.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 10)
        ComboBox16.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 11)
        ComboBox17.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 16)
        ComboBox18.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 22)
        ComboBox22.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 17)
        ComboBox21.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 23)
        TextBox1.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 13)
        TextBox2.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 14)
        TextBox3.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 15)
        TextBox4.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 19)
        TextBox5.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 20)
        TextBox6.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 21)
        TextBox7.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 18)
        TextBox8.Value = MainSheet.Cells(i, 12)

        Exit For
     End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you tell us what line is giving you an error.

Comment: Object required. This error occurs if text preceding a dot is not recognized as an object. Make sure of the controls spelling within the code

Comment: Is `MainSheet` the code name for the worksheet with the data?

Comment: @TimWilliams imo looking at his code I doubt he knows how to change the codename. That's probably it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Put `Option Explicit` at the very top of every module to help identify potential problems with variables, objects, properties, etc.  Also, what have you tried so far to solve this?    See [ask] as well as [mcve] and [help/on-topic].